# Draw n cards k times. Probability that we got exactly all red cards at least once?

Tags: probability, card-games

We have a standard deck of 52 cards, that has 26 red and 26 black cards.

We draw n cards from the deck at the same time, then return them and reshuffle. We repeat that k times.

The question: What is the probability that we drew each red card at least once, and we never draw any black card?

I tried to use:
$\binom{52}{26} P(\textrm{exactly all red cards are drawn at least once}) = P(\textrm{we draw exactly 26 different cards})$.

Then $P(\textrm{we draw exactly 26 different cards}) = P(\textrm{we draw exactly 26 different cards | we draw 1st card at least once}) P(\textrm{we draw 1st card at least once}) + P(\textrm{we draw exactly 26 different cards | we never draw  1st card}) P(\textrm{we never draw 1st card}) =  P(\textrm{we draw exactly 25 different cards from a pile of 51}) (1 - (\binom{51}{n} / \binom{52}{n})^k) + P(\textrm{we draw exactly 26 different cards from a pile of 51})  (\binom{51}{n} / \binom{52}{n})^k .$

Then I wanted to repeat it, but it got too complicated, so I was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: I tried to use: 
P(all red cards are drawn at least once) * $\binom{52}{26}$ = P(we draw exactly 26 different cards). Then P(we draw exactly 26 different cards) = P(we draw exactly 26 different cards | we drew 1st card at least once)*P(we drew 1st card at least once) + P(we draw exactly 26 different cards | we never drew  1st card) * P(we never drew 1st card) =  P(we draw exactly 25 different cards from a pile of 51)* $1 - (\binom{51}{n} / \binom{52}{n})^k$ + P(we draw exactly 25 different cards from a pile of 52) * $(\binom{51}{n} / \binom{52}{n})^k$. And then to repeat, but it got too long

Comment: All your work needs to be added to the question to provide context and not in the comments.

Comment: thank you, I will edit it.

Comment: If $p$ is the probability that all $n$ cards are red, then what is the value of $p$?

Comment: of course $n$ must be $ \leq 26$

Comment: I translated the question badly, I'm so sorry. I wanted to ask about probability of a different event, I will edit it.